# WPF Polygon rotatetransform rotates moving direction

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, polygon, rotatetransform

So I'm building this application in WPF where I draw a line with an arrowhead. The arrowhead is a Polygon created in a resource dictionary as shown below:

```
<!-- This is the arrowhead of the wire -->
<Polygon x:Name="PART_arrow"
    Points="{Binding Path=ArrowPathData}" IsHitTestVisible="True"
    Stroke="{TemplateBinding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding InnerWireStrokeThickness}"
    Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" RenderTransform="{Binding ArrowRotation}">
</Polygon>
```

In the viewmodel I'm creating the arrowhead with a pointcollection with it's position depending on the position of the last joint of the line. In the end the arrowhead needs to rotate according to the angle of the line but this is for later. On this moment the Arrowhead is visualised and follows the last joint of the line. This only works when the rotation of the arrowhead is 0. When I change the rotation, the movement of the arrowhead changes too. So e.g. when I set the rotation to 90 degrees. the arrowhead rotates 90 degrees, but when I move the line to the left, the arrowhead moves to the top. I tried to change the RenderTransform setter to LayoutTransform. And I used Polygon.Rendertransform and hardcoded a angle. but nothing works.

```
public PointCollection ArrowPathData
{
    get
    {
        PointCollection arrow = new PointCollection();

        if(isArrowSelected)
            arrow = PointCollection.Parse("0,0 3,5 0,0 -3,5");
        else if (isWindowSelected)
            arrow = PointCollection.Parse("0,0 5,10 0,20 -5,10");
        else if (isRoofSelected)
            arrow = PointCollection.Parse("0,0 5,10 -5,10");

        IEnumerable<WireJoint> joints = Joints;
        if (joints.Count<WireJoint>() > 0)
        {
            WireJoint lastJoint = joints.Last();

            if (lastJoint != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrow.Count; i++)
                {
                    arrow[i] = new Point(lastJoint.Point.X + arrow[i].X - Offset.X, lastJoint.Point.Y + arrow[i].Y - Offset.Y);
                }
            }
            return arrow;
        }
        else
            return new PointCollection();
    }
}

public RotateTransform ArrowRotation
{
    get
    {
        return new RotateTransform(45) ;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Edit: Added extra arrowheads in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a Binding Converter that creates a transformed Geometry from the last two points of a Polyline:

```
public class ArrowHeadConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Geometry geometry = null;
        var points = value as IList<Point>;

        if (points != null && points.Count >= 2)
        {
            geometry = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L5,10 -5,10Z").Clone();

            var lastPoint = points[points.Count - 1];
            var lastSegment = lastPoint - points[points.Count - 2];
            var angle = Vector.AngleBetween(new Vector(0, -1), lastSegment);
            var transform = Matrix.Identity;

            transform.Rotate(angle);
            transform.Translate(lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y);

            geometry.Transform = new MatrixTransform(transform);
        }

        return geometry;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You can use the converter like in this simple example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <local:ArrowHeadConverter x:Key="ArrowHeadConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Polyline x:Name="polyline" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
              Points="10,10 50,20 70,40 80,60"/>

    <Path Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
          Data="{Binding Points, ElementName=polyline,
                         Converter={StaticResource ArrowHeadConverter}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I edited my code, I forgot to tell you there are different arrowheads to display, so there is no fixed pointscollection size.

Comment: You may add a property to the converter that defines the arrow head points.

Comment: How do I add a property to the converter?

Comment: ArrowHeadConverter is a class. You should be able to declare a property in that class. If it needs to be bindable, add a custom dependency property.

Comment: I can't bind to an property in the converterclass. I get this error: " A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Relationship' property of type 'ArrowHeadConverter'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."
This is de xaml and C# code i use on this moment:
http://pastebin.com/mz7hVu1e

Comment: As said, if it needs to be bindable, add a custom dependency property. The converter class must be derived from DependencyObject then.

Comment: I had never used DependencyObject. But it works now, thank you very much